# Best Actuator to Behavioural Positive/Negative Feedback on Cat

Tags: sensors

Rhetorical, yet silly question: Given an Arduino to manage, what would be the easiest way, in terms of available actuators (price/availability counts) to:

a) Apply a positive feedback to a cat, in exchange for a good action?

b) Apply a *NEGATIVE* feedback to a cat, like trying to reach forbidden places?

Comment: Err, don't we have an *actuators* tag?

Comment: This constitutes animal abuse. You should not have a cat if this is how you are thinking of treating him.

Comment: To anyone downvoting: Next time you laugh at Blender Defender, please remind of your hypocrisy. I'm not aiming at torture, just negative feedback.

Comment: That's what the CIA said; it wasn't torture, it was advanced interrogation techniques. I don't know what blender defender is. If what you are doing induces discomfort in the cat, it's animal abuse. You should also try to improve your English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the negative feedback, you could use a loud, screetching noise. I would suspect, however, that the cat would eventually get used to it and ignore it.

Depending on your cat's tastes, you could use the same hardware for positive feedback - playing, for example, a Mozart tune if that's what your cat is into.

I know, a silly answer, but what can you do with a silly question? ;-)